# Unable to register an app on a local server

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to register an app on a newly installed local server (Win 10 home). The error message is 
2020-05-26 07:13:25.274 ERROR 13112 --- [nio-9393-exec-6] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice         : Caught exception while handling a request

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 5: file:\J:\batch-repo\Batch\target\Batch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Is the URI definition correct for a windows environment? or am I making a silly mistake here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things on a windows environment - 1. remove the spaces in the directory structure 2. use forward slash instead of windows default of \ for explorer. It allowed me to register the app now. thanks.